# A fibrant-objects structure on $\bf Top$

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

One can [define](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2926) (Paragraph 1.5, page 10) a fibrant-object structure on a suitable cartesian closed category of topological spaces $\bf Top$, called the $\pi_0$-fibrant structure:

1. A $\pi_0$-equivalence is a map inducing a bijection at the level of $\pi_0$
2. A $\pi_0$-fibration is a continuous map $p\colon E\to B$ having the RLP with respect to the map $\{0\}\to [0,1]$ including the 0:
   $$
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   \{0\} & \to & E \\
   \downarrow &\nearrow_{\exists \alpha}& \downarrow p\\
   [0,1] &\to_{\forall\gamma} & B
   \end{array}
   $$
   Every property defining a fibrant structure can be easily shown in the way you see.

Now I'm interested in extending this. The natural definition for a $\pi_n$-equivalence is a map $A\to B$ indcuing isomorphisms $\pi_i(A)\to \pi_i(B)$ for all $0\le i\le n$.

> What should a $\pi_n$-fibration be in order to define a fibrant structure $\pi_n\text{-}\bf Top$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$?
>
> What if we "go to the limit" (and can it be done?) $\varinjlim_n \big(\pi_n\text{-}\bf Top\big)$ of these fibrant structures? Do we recover a known fibrant structure, obtained forgetting cofibrations and mutual lifting properties of a suitable model structure, on $\bf Top$?

Comment: I add as a comment what I tried to do: "having the RLP with respect to $\{0\}\to [0,1]$" can be generalized in "having the RLP with respect to *any* of the $i+2$ inclusions $\triangle_i\to \triangle_{i+1}$, $\triangle_i$ being the $i$-simplex. I strongly suspect I'm asking too much in some ways, and not enough in others.

Comment: Probably this should be asked at mathoverflow ;).